# Replace an image wherever it is used - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to replace an image that could be used anywhere on a page.

So if we have an example html page like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

       <img id="1" src="example.com/img/1889.png">

       <div style="background: url('example.com/img/1889.png')">
       <div>

       <a>
           <img id="2" src="example.com/img/1889.png">
       </a>

   </body>

</html>
```

Where ever - **example.com/img/1889.png** - appears, it must be replaced with something else.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately I can't use any javascript libraries. Its for a browser plugin. Nor can I use browser specific APIs

Comment: Why does this have to be done with JavaScript?

Comment: If the image will only be used within `<img>`-tags, you can use `.getElementsByTagName('img')` function to get all img-tags and then compare the src-Attribute to whatever image you are looking for and if it matches replace it.

Comment: If that is the case then try this `$("body").html($("body").html().replace('old image','new image'));`

Comment: You can use jQuery in a plugin. Why could you not? Even userscripts can request a dependency.

Comment: @Jan - The plugin loads a script dynamically, here in South africa internet speeds are disgustingly slow so every Kb matters. The client doesnt want load times to be any longer than need be. Its all about performance. So if i can not use jQuery and thus use one less http request, all the better

Comment: @DustinSilk if you use jQuery from a CDN, with 99% chance jQuery will already be cached. Noted, however.

Answer (score 4):

There might be some syntax errors here, but basically just try something like:

```
<script>
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        if (imgs[i].src == "oldImg")
            imgs[i].src = "newImg";
        }
    }
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].style.backgroundImage == "oldImg")
            divs[i].style.backgroundImage = "newImg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If that is the case then try this `$("body").html($("body").html().replace('old image','new image'));`

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you're looking for:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('[src]'), // all image and input elements
    styled = document.querySelectorAll('[style]'), // all elements with inline style
    iLen = images.length,
    sLen = styled.length,
    url = 'example.com/img/1889.png', // the string you're searching for
    str = 'some/string', // replace with whatever you choose
    i;

// check for 'example.com/img/1889.png' in image source
for (i = 0; i < iLen; i += 1) {
    if (images[i].src.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
        images[i].src = str;
    }
}

// check for 'example.com/img/1889.png' in either background or background-image
for (i = 0; i < sLen; i += 1) {
    if (styled[i].style.backgroundImage.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
        styled[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + str + ')';
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fycTm/4/)

Comment: The differences between this answer and the previous are (1) this checks all elements that use that string, not just images and divs, and (2) an equality test for this string will fail for both foreground and background images, so using `.indexOf()` to match the string.